# Recoger id de un archivo con clic derecho

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones

Estoy diseñando una app web, una nube. Cuando subo un archivo la base de datos de la un ID, muestro por pantalla el archivo en cuestión. Hasta aqui sin problemas, el problema me viene cuando quiero realizar X acción sobre ese archivo. Tengo deshabilitado el clic derecho para mostrar un menú con varias funciones.

[image: Menu clic derecho]

La pregunta es, como puedo saber sobre que archivo(id) hice clic derecho? y luego como puedo saber que opción del menú he seleccionado y sobre que archivo?

Llevo varios dias atascado aqui, espero que puedan ayudarme.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
             
  //Ocultamos el menú al cargar la página
  $("#menu_derecho").hide();
             
  /* mostramos el menú si hacemos click derecho con el ratón */
  $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e){
    $("#menu_derecho").css({'display':'block', 'left':e.pageX, 'top':e.pageY});
    return false;
  });
             
             
  //cuando hagamos click, el menú desaparecerá
  $(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.button == 0){
      $("#menu_derecho").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
             
  //si pulsamos escape, el menú desaparecerá
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
      $("#menu_derecho").css("display", "none");
    }
  });                      
});
```

```css
div#menu_derecho ul{
 list-style: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 list-style-position: outside;
}
   
div#menu_derecho li{
 list-style: none;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #800;
}

div#menu_derecho li a:hover{
 box-shadow: 250px 0 0 0 #FF7A62 inset;
}

div#menu_derecho li a{
 line-height: 30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #FFF;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease;
 transition: all .3s ease;
}

div#menu_derecho li a span{
 float: right;
 padding-top: 7px;
}
   
div#menu_derecho{
 width:170px;
 position:absolute;   
 background: tomato;   
 border:1px solid #800;
 z-index: 999999;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease;
 transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" >
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/clicderecho.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>  
  <script  src="js/clicderecho.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="menu_derecho">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Copiar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Compartir</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Descargar</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="cuerpo">
   <ul>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" id="1">Fichero 1</spam></li>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" id="2">Fichero 2</spam></li>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" id="3">Fichero 3</spam></li>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" id="4">Fichero 4</spam></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Me gustaria que el resultado final sea un alert diciendo (por ejemplo) "Has seleccionado Descargar sobre el fichero con id 2"**

Answer (score 2):

Una opción que tienes es añadir una clase al menú que aparece al hacer click derecho:

```
<li><a href="#" class="nom_menu">Copiar</a></li>
```

Después obtener el `id` seleccionado con el [event.which](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) (te devuelve 1 para el click izquierdo, 2 para el central y 3 para el derecho)

```
var idSelec;
  $('.nom_fic').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 3:
            idSelec = $(this).attr("id");
            break;
    }
});
```

Y finalmente en el evento `click` de la clase del menú mostrar el alert:

```
$('.nom_menu').click(function(){
    alert("Has seleccionado " + $(this).html() + " sobre el fichero con id " +  idSelec);
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
             
  //Ocultamos el menú al cargar la página
  $("#menu_derecho").hide();
             
  /* mostramos el menú si hacemos click derecho con el ratón */
  $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e){
    $("#menu_derecho").css({'display':'block', 'left':e.pageX, 'top':e.pageY});
    return false;
  });
         
  var idSelec;
  $('.nom_fic').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 3:
            idSelec = $(this).attr("id");
            break;
    }
});       

$('.nom_menu').click(function(){
 alert("Has seleccionado " + $(this).html() + " sobre el fichero con id " +  idSelec);
})

             
  //cuando hagamos click, el menú desaparecerá
  $(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.button == 0){
      $("#menu_derecho").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
             
  //si pulsamos escape, el menú desaparecerá
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
      $("#menu_derecho").css("display", "none");
    }
  });                      
});
```

```css
div#menu_derecho ul{
 list-style: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 list-style-position: outside;
}
   
div#menu_derecho li{
 list-style: none;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #800;
}

div#menu_derecho li a:hover{
 box-shadow: 250px 0 0 0 #FF7A62 inset;
}

div#menu_derecho li a{
 line-height: 30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #FFF;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease;
 transition: all .3s ease;
}

div#menu_derecho li a span{
 float: right;
 padding-top: 7px;
}
   
div#menu_derecho{
 width:170px;
 position:absolute;   
 background: tomato;   
 border:1px solid #800;
 z-index: 999999;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease;
 transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" >
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/clicderecho.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>  
  <script  src="js/clicderecho.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="menu_derecho">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="nom_menu">Copiar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="nom_menu">Compartir</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="nom_menu">Descargar</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="cuerpo">
   <ul>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" id="1">Fichero 1</spam></li>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" id="2">Fichero 2</spam></li>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" id="3">Fichero 3</spam></li>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" id="4">Fichero 4</spam></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aun asi me quedaria saber que opción del menú he seleccionado desde esa misma función jquery, para posteriormente hacer un ajax con esos datos.

He conseguido saber que opción pulsé pero con otra funcion diferente, entonces tengo los 2 datos pero en 2 funciones diferentes.

Comment: Bueno, pero tienes variables globales para eso. ¿Dónde haces tu llamada ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa es utilizar `data-id="<aqui el id>"` en tu elemento `<span>`.. y luego capturarlo desde el evento del menu contextual con la funcion [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

Cambios al html:

```
<li><spam class="nom_fic" data-id="1">Fichero 1</spam></li>
<li><spam class="nom_fic" data-id="2">Fichero 2</spam></li>
<li><spam class="nom_fic" data-id="3">Fichero 3</spam></li>
<li><spam class="nom_fic" data-id="4">Fichero 4</spam></li>
```

Cambios al javascript:

```
/* mostramos el menú si hacemos click derecho con el ratón */
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e){
  var id = $(e.target).data('id');
  console.log("Has seleccionado el fichero con id", id);
  $("#menu_derecho").css({'display':'block', 'left':e.pageX, 'top':e.pageY});
  return false;
});
```

Luego puedes hacer algo similar para la accion en cuestion como te muestro en el ejemplo de abajo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var seleccionado;
  //Ocultamos el menú al cargar la página
  $("#menu_derecho").hide();
             
  /* mostramos el menú si hacemos click derecho con el ratón */
  $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e){
    // aqui capturas el id establecido en el atributo `data-id`
    seleccionado = $(e.target).data('id');
    console.log("Has seleccionado el fichero con id", seleccionado);
    $("#menu_derecho").css({'display':'block', 'left':e.pageX, 'top':e.pageY});
    return false;
  });
             
             
  //cuando hagamos click, el menú desaparecerá
  $(document).click(function(e){
    var accion = $(e.target).data('accion');
    if(accion){
      console.log("Has seleccionado", accion, "sobre el fichero con id", seleccionado);
      $("#menu_derecho").css("display", "none");
      seleccionado = undefined;
    }
  });
             
  //si pulsamos escape, el menú desaparecerá
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
      $("#menu_derecho").css("display", "none");
    }
  });                      
});
```

```css
div#menu_derecho ul{
 list-style: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 list-style-position: outside;
}
   
div#menu_derecho li{
 list-style: none;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #800;
}

div#menu_derecho li a:hover{
 box-shadow: 250px 0 0 0 #FF7A62 inset;
}

div#menu_derecho li a{
 line-height: 30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #FFF;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease;
 transition: all .3s ease;
}

div#menu_derecho li a span{
 float: right;
 padding-top: 7px;
}
   
div#menu_derecho{
 width:170px;
 position:absolute;   
 background: tomato;   
 border:1px solid #800;
 z-index: 999999;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease;
 transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" >
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/clicderecho.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>  
  <script  src="js/clicderecho.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="menu_derecho">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#" data-accion="copiar">Copiar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-accion="compartir">Compartir</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-accion="descargar">Descargar</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="cuerpo">
   <ul>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" data-id="1">Fichero 1</spam></li>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" data-id="2">Fichero 2</spam></li>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" data-id="3">Fichero 3</spam></li>
    <li><spam class="nom_fic" data-id="4">Fichero 4</spam></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y ya por último, para poder usar esos datos y poder meterlo en un div#resultado? cuando pongo 

      $('#resultado').html("<p>Has seleccionado",accion,"sobre el fichero con id",id_archivo);

En el div#resultado solo me aparece "Has seleccionado"